# How do i Submit something to a .txt file in a GUI Edit Box?

Tags: autohotkey

So I had a question about this AHK Script it's basically an encrypter and decrypter. If you run the program you will need to input a password first and then you get to the real program so if you input a string inside of there and "Encode" it is there any way you can Save the "Encoded" string into a .txt with just a button?

I tried some stuff I found on the Internet with Submit and so but i didn't really figure it out. So I am kinda stuck here!

````
SetBatchLines -1
StringCaseSense Off
AutoTrim Off
Hotkey, !x, Exit

InputBox, pass ,Encrypter 1.0, Please enter the Password , HIDE, 190, 140
ifEqual  pass, pass, GoSub, key 
IfNotEqual, pass, pass, MsgBox , 0, Wrong Password, The password was incorrect please try again or press "ESC" to Exit the Programm
IfNotEqual, pass, pass, Reload   

Sleep, 100
;----------------Interface--------------
Gui, 1: Add, Edit, x10 y10 w280 r8 vEncDec
Gui, 1: Font, bold
Gui, 1: Add, Text,, Copy and paste your raw text here to encrypt it.
Gui, 1: Color, d80101
Gui, 1: Add, Button, x10 y150 w75 gENCRYPT, Encode
Gui, 1: Add, Button, x10 y178 w75 gDELETE, Delete
Gui, 1: Add, Button, x110 y150 w75 gDECRYPT, Decode
Gui, 1: Add, Button, x110 y178 w75 gOPEN, Save
Gui, 1: Add, Button, x215 y150 w75 gExit, Exit
Gui, 1: Add, Button, x215 y178 w75 gCREATE, Create
Gui, 1: Show, w300 h208, Encrypter v1.0
Return
;------------------MANAGMENT---------------
DELETE:
    MsgBox, 262208, WARNING!, If you delete the .txt all your Saved Passwords will be deleted!
    Sleep 500
    MsgBox, 262196, WARNING!, Do you really want to delete the .txt?
    IfMsgBox Yes
    FileDelete, %Temp%\ttcrashes.txt
return

CREATE:
    MsgBox, 262208, WARNING!, If you create a new .txt your old .txt file may get deleted!
    Sleep 500
    MsgBox, 262196, WARNING!, Do you really want to create a new .txt?
    IfMsgBox Yes
    FileAppend,ENCODED:, %Temp%\ttcrashes.txt
return

OPEN:
Run, %Temp%\ttcrashes.txt
return
;-------------------Key--------------------
key:
k1 := 0x5025124     ;in each of these 5 keys edit the last 10 0s to random numbers so that they are each different and look something like this: 0x1928374659
k2 := 0x0681035170
k3 := 0x9704313523
k4 := 0x0427880892
k5 := 0x8754345242
return
;----------------Exit HK--------------------
Exit:
ExitApp
return
;-----------------------------------------------

;#############################################################################################################

ENCRYPT:
encrypt = 1
decrypt = 0
GoSub, EncryptDecrypt
Return

DECRYPT:
decrypt = 1
encrypt = 0
GoSub, EncryptDecrypt
Return

;#############################################################################################################

EncryptDecrypt:
Gui, 1: Submit, NoHide

i = 9
p = 0
L =

Loop % StrLen(EncDec)
{
    i++
    If i > 8
   {
      u := p
      v := k5
      p++
      TEA(u,v, k1,k2,k3,k4)
      Stream9(u,v)
      i = 0
   }

    StringMid c, EncDec, A_Index, 1
    a := Asc(c)

    If a between 32 and 126
    {
      If encrypt = 1
      {
         a += s%i%
         IfGreater a, 126, SetEnv, a, % a-95
         c := Chr(a)
      }
      If decrypt = 1   
      {
         a -= s%i%
         IfLess a, 32, SetEnv, a, % a+95
         c := Chr(a)
      }
    }

   L = %L%%c%
}
GuiControl,, EncDec, %L%
Return

;#############################################################################################################

TEA(ByRef y,ByRef z,k0,k1,k2,k3) ; (y,z) = 64-bit I/0 block
{                                ; (k0,k1,k2,k3) = 128-bit key
   IntFormat = %A_FormatInteger%
   SetFormat Integer, D          ; needed for decimal indices
   s := 0
   d := 0x9E3779B9
   Loop 32
   {
      k := "k" . s & 3           ; indexing the key
      y := 0xFFFFFFFF & (y + ((z << 4 ^ z >> 5) + z  ^  s + %k%))
      s := 0xFFFFFFFF & (s + d)  ; simulate 32 bit operations
      k := "k" . s >> 11 & 3
      z := 0xFFFFFFFF & (z + ((y << 4 ^ y >> 5) + y  ^  s + %k%))
   }
   SetFormat Integer, %IntFormat%
   y += 0
   z += 0                        ; Convert to original ineger format
}

Stream9(x,y)                     ; Convert 2 32-bit words to 9 pad values
{                                ; 0 <= s0, s1, ... s8 <= 94
   Local z                       ; makes all s%i% global
   s0 := Floor(x*0.000000022118911147) ; 95/2**32
   Loop 8
   {
      z := (y << 25) + (x >> 7) & 0xFFFFFFFF
      y := (x << 25) + (y >> 7) & 0xFFFFFFFF
      x  = %z%
      s%A_Index% := Floor(x*0.000000022118911147)
   }
}



Esc::
ExitApp
return```

Well my expected result would be that if you press the "Save" Button on the GUI you the "Encoded" string gets saved into the .txt
````

Comment: You have written `FileAppend,ENCODED:, %Temp%\ttcrashes.txt`, this adds the actual text "ENCODED:" to the file. Change it to `FileAppend,%EncDec%, %Temp%\ttcrashes.txt`

Answer (score 0):

As stated above by Yane, the correct syntax is FileAppend [, Text, Filename, Encoding]

Using one of the below should create/modify the file as intended.

```
FileAppend,ENCODED: %VariableName%, %Temp%\ttcrashes.txt
```

or

```
FileAppend,%VariableName%, %Temp%\ttcrashes.txt
```